# Stop MS Word opening files automatically on launch

Tags: macos, ms-office

Continual opening of files from history. I clear history, but they appear on startup the next time. If I use option (alt) button on 'Word' dropdown, I get Quit and keep files rather than Quit and close files?

Comment: What version of office? 2008? 2011? Office 365? What version of OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Clear the saved state, rather than the history.
Quit Word.

From Finder
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd> 
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>     <kbd>G</kbd>  
Copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State`

Delete the folder com.microsoft.Word.savedState

Relaunch Word.

For future reference, whatever is open when you quit will reopen when you launch. The trick is to close documents before quitting.

You can stop all applications from remembering their state using System Prefs > General > Close Windows when quitting an app.

Alternatively, there's a $0.99 app called [RestoreMeNot](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/restoremenot-disable-window/id915578546?mt=12) which can switch on a per-app basis.